# After updating Xcode I have issues linking libraries. ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT and ARMV7S

Tags: ipad, xcode4.5, iphone-5, armv7

After updating the Xcode, my iPad app doesn't compile.
It has a library called Flurry and the compiler says:
"ld: file is universal but doesnt caontain armv7s slice...libFlurry.a"

So, it seems to me Flurry has not been compiled including the armv7s (or iPhone 5) architecture.
Hoever, my app it's only for iPad (iPad 1, 2 and 3)

As far as I know, the armv7s belongs to the iPhone 5 architecture, but none of the current iPads have that architecture.
Am I right?
Does it mean I can change "$(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)" by "armv7"?
I did it and now the program works perfectly on my iPad, but not sure if this is right, because perhaps the not all iPads are armv7.
Is there any constant for only iPads architectures?

Answer (score 1):

yes, because flurry lib was compiled for armv7 only so flurry lib will not support to armv7s.

So making code work with armv7s, you need to update flurry lib.

But if you just want to run app in armv7 then remove armv7s from build setting.

thanks